# Qooxdoo in existing project

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I am having a problem with the optimized version of my qooxdoo application. The thing is, I am trying to use qooxdoo in an existing application spread across many Javascript files and has a fairly complicated structure. To integrate qooxdoo I just generated an application and included it in my HTML project and it works. However, when I try to do:

./generate.py build

to generate an optimized version of the library, the generator optimizes out qooxdoo classes and widgets which I am not using even though I am in my project. I want to generate an optimized, minified version of qooxdoo library with "everything". Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak your config to include all (interesting) qooxdoo framework classes. You basically have to add `qx.*` and will want to exclude some unwanted namespaces beneath that, in the `build-script` job. E.g. in your config.json add something like:

```
"jobs": {
    "build-script" : {
        "include" : ["qx.*"],
        "exclude" : ["qx.test.*", "qx.dev.unit.*"]
    }
}
```

Have a look at the `application/playground` config in the SDK, the Playground app uses a similar approach.